# Elm ports not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, elm

I am having a problem getting Elm ports working with Firefox.

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Firefox Ports</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my `index.js`:

```
"use strict";

require("./index.html");

const Elm = require("./Main.elm");
const app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
console.log("here");

window.onload = function() {
    console.log("window.onload");
    app.ports.sayHello.subscribe(function(who) {
        console.log("Greetings,", who);
    });
};
```

And here is my `Main.elm`:

```
port module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (Html, div, text)


type Msg
    = None


type alias Model =
    {}


initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    {}


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( initialModel, sayHello "Foo" )


port sayHello : String -> Cmd msg


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    Html.program
        { init = init
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        , view = view
        }


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    ( model, Cmd.none )


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ text "Hello" ]
```

In the chrome console, the output shows that the port function is called when the model is initialized (`init`):

```
11:00:47.320 app.js:9181 here
11:00:47.371 app.js:9184 window.onload
11:00:47.464 app.js:9186 Greetings, Foo
```

clearly showing that the port function is called, but in Firefox, the last line (`Greetings, Foo`) is missing:

```
here
window.onload
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you move the `subscribe()` call just after the `fullscreen()` call? (before logging `"here"`)

Comment: It works, so the problem must not be with the ports. I actually simplified this from a larger program that is trying to control a modal dialog that uses the Google dialog-polyfill. I will need to investigate that one more.

Comment: @ChadGilbert It is working in Firefox, including the dialog polyfill. Not sure why the `window.onload` was a problem. If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving the `subscribe()` call to occur right after the call to `fullscreen()` to remove the possibility of a race condition:

```
const app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
app.ports.sayHello.subscribe(function(who) {
    console.log("Greetings,", who);
});
console.log("here");

window.onload = function() {
    console.log("window.onload");
};
```

My hunch is that the event cycles in Firefox ran the Elm code *prior* to `window.onload` at a time when there were no subscriptions to the port. This is just a hunch, but I think best practice dictates that you set up your subscriptions as soon as you create the app.

Comment: I also added a port to register each dialog with `dialogPolyfill`, and it works, but I'm going to try to move that part into a `window.onload` function so that all elements with the tag `dialog` get registered automatically.